# Hello.js - Flickr API auth not displaying login form but rather close it

Tags: javascript, flickr, hello.js

I'm using `Hello.js` to handle Flickr API. The problem I'm facing now is that when user clicks on Flickr button to get `/me/albums` from Flickr, the popup window appears and closes itself right away without asking for login.

However, the same code does work for Facebook as it does open the popup and asks for login before closing when the user click Submit.

What is the possible problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't registered your client id with an [oauth-proxy](http://adodson.com/hello.js/#oauth-proxy) service perhaps?

The default is https://auth-server.herokuapp.com